# Problems with using flexbox for vertically aligning

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a page-wide wrapping div that has flexbox alignment to center:

```
.app_container{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding: 10px;
}
```

In this wrapper, I have a menu that can vary in height as the user expands submenus. The problem is when the menu becomes vertically bigger than the window height. Some parts of the menu gets cut off at the top.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd7es.jpg

One solution that I found was to simply get overflow: auto on the menu. But that causes the scroll bar to appear on the menu, not on the page wrapper. I want the scroll bar to be on the page wrapper.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrRw6.jpg

Don't think it is relevant, but I use React.

Here is codepen: https://codepen.io/GuacomoleCyclone/pen/xxEoary

EDIT: I've stumbled upon a solution. I've added this and it solved all problems:

```
html, body{
display: grid;
}
```

Comment: please can you produce a [mcve] with both your html and css

Comment: I've added a codepen link

Comment: can you please check codepen link. It's look like you didn't complete it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what your codepen is showing, the issue seems to be coming from setting the width and height on the `html` element. You want to change:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

to

```css
html, body { 
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This does fix the issue if the item is bigger than the window height. In my codepen example I just have a static sized square, but in the actual app I have slidedowns that increase or decrease the height. When this fix is applied and the menu is smaller than window height, this happens - https://imgur.com/a/4sebFth

Comment: Maybe you're looking to set the body to `100vh` instead of `100%`? Otherwise can you add additional code to your example to repro the issue?